# dividing datetimes by date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I save my news in db and each news have an field that save it's datetime in format:
 `xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx`
and now I want retrieve news by date `xxxx-xx-xx` and for example `today` what I must write in `where` of my sql code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple:

`SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE DATE( datetime_field ) = DATE( NOW( ) )`

> please notice that DATE() return only date value and NOW() return current datetime

Answer (score 2):

use `DATE` function. eg

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE DATE(columnName) = '2012-12-20'
```

this will retrieve all records where date is December 20, 2012.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from TableName
where 
DATE_FORMAT(columnName,'%m-%d-%Y') = '01-01-2012'
```